# numpy vectorize function receiving pixel's r,g,b values

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, vectorization

I have a function :

```
def co(pixel):
    print(pixel)
    #return [res]
    return pixel
```

And I'm trying to transform my 3d array with this :

```
v = np.vectorize(co)
#v.excluded.add(1)

new_arr = v(arr)

print(new_arr)
```

But what it is interesting is, it prints out each pixel's r,g,b values. Instead of that, shouldn't it print pixels ?

My real question is how can I iterate over all pixel in my image and apply this transformation.

Initially my image looks like this :

```
[[[239 255 138]
  [239 255 138]
  [239 255 138]
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can iterate through your 3-D matrix.
Let me know if you are trying to apply filters like(horizontal,vertical filters) to your image

```
 for i in range(l):
    for j in range(b):
        for k in range(h):
              print(ar[i][j][k])
              #do your function
```